# How to loop usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, user-controls

I have problem displaying `usercontrol`,I have a `usercontrol` which has a panel called `rowpanel` which  has `textbox` and `combobox`,Now ,when I Click `button_1`,I want the `usercontrol` to  be displayed on each click,it is like adding a row on each click,I just don`t know how to loop it,I tried using indexing...

**CODE**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            AddRow add = new AddRow();
            show_pnl.Controls.Add(add);
        }
```

**AddRow** is `usercontrol` ...this is a windows application,can I get some help please,

Comment: What do you mean lopp through? Do you want to add the new instance at a specific place in your panel ?

Comment: @ ryadavilli ,Hello,I want a new instance of the panel(which contains text box) to be added on every click sequentially.Can you please help me solve this,I am stuck with this issues for very long

Comment: What is AddRow here? is it not the panel that you want?

Comment: Its not very clear what you want. Every click you are adding the **AddRow** `UserControl`. You say you dont know how to loop it or do it sequentially, what does that mean??

Comment: @ryadavilli , AddRow is my usercontrol,Show_pnl is my panel where I want contents of AddRow displayed,when I click button_1,it displays AddRow content just once,I want it to be displayed every time I click the button

Comment: Then check the UI positioning of the AddRow control. It seems multiple controls are getting added but being shown at the same place. Your code for adding the new control is fine. You might want to set the top and left of the new control you are adding on every click.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson,hello Jermey,What I mean is ,Let`s say every click has a count,when I click twice,count is 2,then,I have to be able to see 2 AddRow ,the contents of AddRow on the show_pnl has to be displayed twice,how do I display the contents of AddRow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because they are overlapping each other. To fix it increment the top &/or left as shown here:

```
private const int gap = 20;
private int count = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var add = new UserControl1();
    add.Top = count * (add.Height + gap);
    show_pnl.Controls.Add(add);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Jeremy, you might want to call out that 20 is a random number of your choosing and the OP should put a proper value there :)

Comment: @Jeremy ,Thank You so much Buddy,I was stuck with this problem from past three days,you made my life so much easier...Thank you so much